# Decompressed file too big

Tags: powershell

I am trying to program a script that gets a zip file from the internet and extracts a single file from it to disk using streams.

The problem is that the extracted file is too big.

- Compressed Size: 30 kb
- Original Size: 373 kb
- Decompressed Size: 825kb

I would be glad if someone could help me find what's wrong with my code. I very much like to get an answer using streams.

The file that is downloaded (as of today) is: https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/downloads/love-0.10.2-win64.zip

My code:

```
### Download current LOVE framework executable ###

# By default PowerShell supports only SSL3 and TLS1.0, add TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 support.
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'

# Get current version of the LOVE framework

$request = Invoke-WebRequest "https://love2d.org/"
$downloadUri = (Select-String -InputObject $request.Content -Pattern "https://bitbucket\.org/rude/love/downloads/love-.*-win64\.zip").Matches[0].Value
$loveBinaryStream = (Invoke-WebRequest $downloadUri).RawContentStream

# Extract love.exe
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
$zipArchive = New-Object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive($loveBinaryStream)
$zipEntry = $zipArchive.Entries | ? { $_.Name -eq "love.exe" }

$stream = $zipEntry.Open()
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream)
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("love.exe")
$sw.Write($sr.ReadToEnd())
$sw.Close()
$sr.Close()
$stream.Close()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the output file?  I'd try using Format-Hex to see what's in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was some kind of encoding issue.

Anyways, substituting this:

```
$stream = $zipEntry.Open()
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream)
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("love.exe")
$sw.Write($sr.ReadToEnd())
$sw.Close()
$sr.Close()
$stream.Close()
```

for this

```
# Save to disk
$sw = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($tempLovePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
$stream = $zipEntry.Open()
$stream.CopyTo($sw)
$stream.Close()
$sw.Close()
```

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
### Download current LOVE framework executable ###

# By default PowerShell supports only SSL3 and TLS1.0, add TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 support.
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'

# Get current version of the LOVE framework

$request = Invoke-WebRequest "https://love2d.org/"
$downloadUri = (Select-String -InputObject $request.Content -Pattern "https://bitbucket\.org/rude/love/downloads/love-.*-win64\.zip").Matches[0].Value
$loveBinaryStream = (Invoke-WebRequest $downloadUri).RawContentStream

# Extract love.exe
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.io.compression.filesystem # for the System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions
$zipArchive = New-Object System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive($loveBinaryStream)
$zipEntry = $zipArchive.Entries | ? { $_.Name -eq "love.exe" }
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($zipEntry, "path_to_file")
```

Comment: Thanks, good advice. However, I'd like to use streams. I'm sorry I didn't mention it. You got an idea for that, too?